# Is a double fusion possible?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball

We know that there are 2 possible ways of performing a fusion.

1. Potara earrings
2. Fusion dance

**Is it possible to combine these 2?**

For example we have 4 individuals. They form 2 pairs which are perfectly synced with each other for the fusion dance. Once fused they wear each a potaro earring resulting in the second fusion. Is this actually possible? If potara earrings can't be used on a fused body then we can have 2 sets of earrings for the pairs. The fused ones perform the dance for the final fusion.

Comment: To have fusion with Fusion dance technique, both should have same amount of power, which we may not be sure in case of one with potara earring and one with fusion dance, and then fusion dance of both, as both power level may differ.

Comment: So the correct order of operations for this would be: 1 - pairs (with same amount of power) perform fusion dance to fuse. 2 - fused pairs wear potara earrings in order to fuse. Potara earring doesn't require same power levels for fusion so logically said this should work.

Comment: If you are asking about saiyans, if it's possible or not it's pure speculation since we havent seen it in the series and as far as I know it wasnt stated anywhere. Other characters perform more than one fusion though, and you probably know it (Buu, Namekians, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this question is something which cannot be answered definitely as the actual answer completely relies on the authors.

First combination(Potara fused characters do a potara fusion after) : It was stated by the Old Kai in the manga that the potara earring cannot be used more than once. In other words, 2 fused characters cannot fuse with potara fusion. This is because, one fused character such as Vegito cannot take off a potara earring as both the characters would both need 2 have 1 potara earring on.

Second combination(Potara fusion followed by fusion dance/Fusion dance followed by potara fusion/ Fusion dance followed by another fusion dance): Although dragon ball GT is not canon, It was indicated that even the fusion dance can only sustain a fusion powerful to a certain extent because we see SSJ4 Gogeta defuse before the time limit. We know for a fact that the potara fusion is a lot more powerful and with 2 potara fused characters (Match their power level's and fuse), the power would be enormous and they wouldn't be able to sustain the fusion. The only other option would be a bunch of weak characters first doing the potara fusion and then followed with the fusion dance. So lets say a very weak race(Humans), do the potaro fusion, for instance krillin, tien, yamcha and roshi. In the Buu saga, Base goku and base vegeta were no where as strong as Super buu Yet alone buu han. Yet  we see base vegito completely owning him. So even if these 4 humans do a potara fusion followed by the fusion dance, the probability of the fusion of their fused character lasting would be very low and they would very likely immediately split back to their potara fused characters. We see goku willing to fuse with Hercule before his fight with Buuhan(Before Vegeta showed up). So goku did believe that even fusion with hercule would've made him stronger to an extent. So that leaves us with the possibility of someone as weak as Hercule and say his students doing the same. They would be able to attain the potara fusions but wouldn't have the necessary skills to perform the fusion dance.

This would apply in case of all the 3 other possibilities listed in the second combination. This answer would be making an assumption such that fused characters can fuse. However, let us consider another possibility. In the Saiyan Saga, once Goku arrives to fight Vegeta and Nappa, we see him split a senzu bean and give half of it to Krillin and the other half to Gohan. We notice that this doesn't completely heal their energy. So let's say the effects of the Senzu bean were cut down to 50%? So what if Goku ate 2 successive senzu beans, instead of 1 when he's out of stamina. His body is not going to create an additional energy source after the energy from the first Senzu bean is depleted. So in other words, one could say a body is capable of only adapting to 1 fusion and another fusion wouldn't be possible?

Comment: The senzu bean example is a good one. The 4 beings controlling 1 body would most likely result in something way to chaotic and therefor making them unable to accept at most 2 minds in 1 body. But yeah fusion dance has a lot limitations that's why it made me curious if a stable successful fusion dance followed with potara fusion would be possible. But as described in your second possibility it would be highly unstable and most likely split immediately. I am curious about whether the authors in the future will give some hints about this.